# CSS3Pie position relative and bloc above/under others

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm using **css3pie** for my design on internet explorer, but I have some trouble.
previous dropdown menu won't disappear, div block are displayed above menu, etc... here the capture :

[image]

It should work like this (chrome), of course it's not working on IE

[image]

If I don't use the following css position property css3pie is not rendering :

```
position: relative;
```

I think it is for this reason that my blocks are not nested correctly. but I don't know how to do whitout it...

Comment: don't support ie8? or give it square corners

Comment: corner, transparency work, but blocks aren't displayed correctly...